# Difference between the words zachor and pakad

Tags: hebrew, words

What is the difference between the words *zachor* and *pakad*?

They are used with what seems like very similar meanings throughout the Rosh HaShanah *davening*, as well as in the *Chumash*.

Here are some uses to consider:

- Noach and Rochel is recalled with *zachor* (*Bereishis* 8:1, 30:22)
- Sarah is recalled with *pakad* (*Bereishis* 21:1)
- It seems like covenants are remembered with *zachor* (e.g. promise to the Patriarchs to redeem Jews from Egypt in *Shemos* 2:24 or promise to rescue the Jews from the exile at the end of the curses in *Vayikra* 26:42)

All explanations I've seen relate *pakod* to *tafkid* (purpose, function, task), for example, someone tried to say that *zachor* is focusing on generic ideas and *pakod* - on what is a particular person's task in realizing these ideas. This seems to fit Sarah, but does not explain how Rochel could be recalled for childbirth (just like Sarah was) with *pakod*.

Would someone be able to connect these for me?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: gt6989b, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for the interesting question. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Malbim ([Bereishis 21:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40102&st=&pgnum=194)) explains that זכר means to remember as it is normally used, and פקד means to remember in order to do something for the person for whom you פקד-ed.

Comment: So how do you learn that Sarah and Rochel were remembered with different words for the same purpose (conception of a child)?

Comment: Another problem would be from *Yirmeya* 2:2 -- "I remembered (*zacharti*) for you the *chessed* of your youth" -- it would sound that G-d's rememberance for us is in order to end the exile, so *pakadti* would fit better according to this understanding, no?

Comment: @gt6989b Malbim explains [there](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40102&st=&pgnum=286) that the "zechirah" by Rachel was that he remembered her good deeds

Comment: The same should work for the verse in Yirmiyahu

Comment: @b_a: But it just seems both rememberances were for the sake of doing something for the object of rememberance. Acoording to Malbim's take, wouldn't then *pakod* fit better? By te way, thank you for an answer with a source, it's very helpful.

Comment: @gt6989b The way I understood Malbim, the פקד is the actual start of the doing the thing for the person, while זכר  in both of your objectionable cases is the *reason* for the doing